# LoadRunner_How to Attach xlsx file in the scripts

Tags: file-upload, loadrunner

Well im new in Load runner Tools honestly speaking morning only i have started the learning these tools and during re_execution time i stuck at one point and regarding that i need to understand how to attach excel-sheet.
in my application there is field where we basically attach the employee data and supporting attachment for these fields always be in excel format.
So i have recorded all these steps using load runner and during re-execution load runner failed and throws following error. i tried lot but not getting any idea how to attach these excel file from my own computer to scripts.

if someone guide me these how to handle these situation ?

Many Thanks

> Error Details

Error65
GBO_UploadSupplierlists.c(65):
Error -26488: Could not obtain information about submitted file "C:\Users\Amit.Bhagwat\Documents\VuGen\Scripts\Supplier-Onboarding Process\ST_Supplier.xlsx": _stat32 rc=-1, errno=2 [No such file or directory]. Using an empty file   [MsgId: MERR-26488]

GBO_UploadSupplierlists.c   C:\Users\Amit.Bhagwat\Documents\VuGen\Scripts\Supplier-Onboarding Process   Supplier-Onboarding Process

Comment: `"Name=FileUpload1", "Value=C:\\Temp\\my_uploaded_file.pdf", "File=yes", ENDITEM,`

Comment: i got above answer thanks